# Finding All Resources In Grakn

Tags: vaticle-typeql, vaticle-typedb

I have created the following simple schema:

```
insert
name sub resource datatype string;
id sub resource datatype string;
person sub entity has name has id;
```

and data:

```
insert
$x isa person has name "Bob" has id bob;
```

How can I get all the resources I have attached to an entity? Do I have to iterate over all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the resources by querying the root resource like so:

```
match $x has resource $y;
```